# Save file to android gallery and scan it

Tags: android, animated-gif, android-file

I am trying to download a `gif` image into `gallery`

my code works perfectly with `png` ,`jpg`

my code dose not work on any `gif`

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:648)`
```

Here is my code

```
private void saveFile(Bitmap bitmap, String name) {

    String filename = "XXX";
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(Environment
            .getExternalStorageDirectory(), "XXX");
    sdImageMainDirectory.mkdirs();
    File outputFile = new File(sdImageMainDirectory, filename);
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, outputFile.toString());
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, filename);
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED, System
            .currentTimeMillis());
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/png");
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/gif");
    Uri uri = mActivity.getContentResolver().insert(
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,values);
    try {
        OutputStream outStream = mActivity.getContentResolver()
                .openOutputStream(uri);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 95, outStream);

        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();


        String filePath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath() + "/" + filename;    
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(mActivity, new String[] { filePath }, null, null);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Unable to create file, likely because external storage is
        // not currently mounted.
        Log.v("ExternalStorage", "Error writing " , e);
    }
}
```

and this is the log

```
11-20 15:14:26.010: E/AndroidRuntime(24838): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-32366
11-20 15:14:26.010: E/AndroidRuntime(24838): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-20 15:14:26.010: E/AndroidRuntime(24838):    at     android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:648)
11-20 15:14:26.010: E/AndroidRuntime(24838):    at android.content.ContentResolver.openOutputStream(ContentResolver.java:540)
11-20 15:14:26.010: E/AndroidRuntime(24838):    at android.content.ContentResolver.openOutputStream(ContentResolver.java:516)
11-20 15:14:26.010: E/AndroidRuntime(24838):    at com.xx.www.MediaFragment.saveFile(MediaFragment.java:2238)
11-20 15:14:26.010: E/AndroidRuntime(24838):    at com.xxx.www.MediaFragment.access$1(MediaFragment.java:2218)
11-20 15:14:26.010: E/AndroidRuntime(24838):    at com.xxx.www.MediaFragment$14$1.run(MediaFragment.java:1849)
11-20 15:14:26.010: E/AndroidRuntime(24838):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Also, check the value of `uri`, if it is getting populated properly...

Comment: content://media/external/images/media/17008 

this is the Uri

Comment: 'values.put(String key, String value)' check the weather you can put two values for single key _MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE_